# ruby on rails tutorial section 3.2 rspec testing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

recently started the RoRTute by Michael Hartl, getting stuck trying my first rspec test in section 3.2, at this point the test is meant to fail but all i get are errors which I'm having a hard time interpreting. I've had a look around but not getting much luck finding a similar error and/or solution. I am brand new to programming and ruby/rails. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**terminal error output**

```
Macintosh:sample_app rails$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 
/Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from /Users/rails/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from /Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

**static_pages_specs.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just visited the site to post a similar question. I am not using Michael's tutorial.  I started getting the error when i added carrierwave gem. https://gist.github.com/vezu/6380850

Comment: It asking for zip library. What if you will add `gem zip` ?

Comment: And it seems you are using old version of gem. Try `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1'` latest

Comment: `"require 'zip/zip'"` if you are using `rubyzip`

Comment: @hawk you are correct.... why not add your comment as an answer, so that we can vote.

Comment: @hawk also tried your zip suggestion with the following result:
`Macintosh:sample_app rails$ gem zip
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command zip
Macintosh:sample_app rails$ gem install zip
Fetching: zip-2.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed zip-2.0.2
1 gem installed
Macintosh:sample_app rails$ gem zip
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command zip`

Comment: @rickmoreira its not command, it should be added to `Gemfile`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you are using old version of gem. Try  `'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1'` latest

Comment: Try `bundle update` or remove `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle install` again.

Comment: thank you, I have used this response. 

If anyone has time, could you explain why this worked? I ask because in the tutorial it often specifies specific versions of gems to use (not necessarily the latest) without any incident, yet here it caused this error.

Comment: It seems that version selenium 2.0.0 using `rubyzip >= 0` which has bug in 1.0.0 https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/90 And selenium 2.35.1 using `rubyzip < 1.0.0` I hope it makes sense for you.