# zip/zip (LoadError) - Breaking guard or rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rspec-rails, guard

I just added gem 'carrierwave' and it's breaking guard rails 4.0. I added rubyzip gem but it won't remedy the issue.  I cannot run any more tests, and i can't figure out how to solve this issue.

**guard --debug**

```
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Command execution: growlnotify --version
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
19:11:40 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Spork
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Command execution: ps aux | grep -v guard | awk '/spork/&&!/awk/{print $2;}'
19:11:40 - DEBUG - Killing Spork servers with PID: 
19:11:40 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
19:11:40 - DEBUG - guard-spork command execution: ["exec", "spork", "-p", "8989"]
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Volumes/Khaya/pumula/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/spork-rails-3224f84d8c31/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:49:in `require'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/spork-rails-3224f84d8c31/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:49:in `preload_rails'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/spork-rails-3224f84d8c31/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:7:in `preload'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/spork:23:in `load'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.9'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 4.2.0'
end
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
end
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '>= 3.0.0.0', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'cocoon', :git => 'git://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.0.rc'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'friendly_id', '5.0.0.beta4' # Note: You MUST use 5.0.0 or greater for Rails 4.0+   
gem 'figaro'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2'
gem 'fog'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
gem 'turbolinks'
```

**logo_uploader.rb**

```
**# encoding: utf-8

class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

end**
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I needed to update `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0`'to `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1`' and the problem all goes away.

Similar question [ruby on rails tutorial section 3.2 rspec testing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526392/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-section-3-2-rspec-testing-error)

Comment: this solved my problem with rake as well. I had selenium-webdriver 2.35.0 and was getting an error with loading zip/zip even though require zip/zip worked fine on the irb.

thanks a lot @Vezu

Answer (score 3):

Adding `gem "zip-zip", "~> 0.1" and gem "rubyzip", "~> 1.0.0"` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

[RubyZip](http://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip) version 1.0.0 changed several class names and the location of the file to require. This has introduced problems when one of your project dependencies relies on the v1.0.0 interface, while another on the v0.9.9 interface. To ease this problem try adding the [zip-zip](http://rubygems.org/gems/zip-zip) gem to your project. It provides a simple adapter for your dependencies using the v0.9.9 interface allowing you to upgrade to RubyZip v1.0.0.