# writing test for rspec using capybara where java script is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my Gemfile i have use

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails' 
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem 'launchy'
end 

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1' 

  # gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

In spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__) 
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.include Capybara::DSL

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false


    config.order = "random"
  end
```

in spec/requests/home_spec.rb

```
describe "Homepage with 'Government Contracts Awarded By Year'", :js => true do
  it  "should have visible" do 
     visit root_path
     page.has_content?('Government Contracts Awarded By Year')
  end

  it "Graph View", :driver => :selenium do 
    page.has_css?('#ui-id-1')
    # $("#by_year_tabs ul li a#ui-id-1").text()
    click_link 'ui-id-1'
  end

  it "Table View", :driver => :selenium do  
    page.has_css?('#ui-id-2')
    # click_link 'ui-id-2'
    page.has_selector?(:xpath, '//table/tr')
  end
end
```

when i run this test on terminal then i got error

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

i have ried many versions of selenium but not fix yet ... please give valuable suggetions to solve this kind of problem  and i am on vagrant in which i have installed firefox as well crome setup already.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can solve your problem: [Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303161/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

briefly:

```
gem update selenium-webdriver
```

Comment: i have tried with this but got error
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)

Comment: Same error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528631/rspec-error-regarding-selenium-webdriver

Maybe a **bundle update** can solve.
Otherwise you can try add **gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip'** to your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this error when you keep your Firefox up to date.

The Selenium webdriver is not yet compatible with the latest FF version.

You should try to download a previous FF version https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

To avoid this problem, I'm locking my FF app : Cmd + i on the FF app and click on Locked, on MacOsx.

When you upgrade you selenium gem, you can also upgrade your FF to the last supported one.