# rspec loaderrror issue during Chapter 3 of Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial book and I'm on [Chapter 3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-first_tests), trying to get the rspec test to fail as it says in the book. The only issue is I keep getting a load error every time I run:
    $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

It returns this:

```
atlas:sample_app Leopard$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-    2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Leopard/Autodidactism/Rails Tutorial/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I've also already scoured all of the questions with this issue but none of the given answers in those seem to work for me. I've been stuck for about 4 hours on this.

I've also reinstalled rspec, made sure my Gemfile was saved and properly updated and installed and still seem to get nowhere.

Here is my current Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec', '2.13.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  # gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

 group :test do
   gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
   gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
   gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
   gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
   gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
end

  gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
  gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
  gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: May need to update selinium-webdriver in gemfile? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526392/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-section-3-2-rspec-testing-error

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. It's had me stuck all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your gemfile.

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
```

to

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1'
```

The the root of your problem.